# text box value should increase while Hslider start drag

Tags: apache-flex

i have one value in text box(eg:1200) once i drag  the HSlider from left to right text box value to increase 1200+150 for each intrevel.if right to left has to decres 150 as same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use binding tag, i read somewhere

do one thing, take one bindable variable

```
[Bindable]private var counter:int;
```

and then, 
set the snap interval of your slider to 150
when you move your slider, put the slider value in this counter variable, ryt

i mean, on the change property of slider, put value of slider in the bindable counter variable

and then in textinput, `<textinput text="{counter}"/>`

Answer (score 2):

```
<mx:HSlider id="slider" minimum="0" maximum="10" snapInterval="1" liveDragging="true"/>
<mx:Label text="{1200 + slider.value*150}"/>
```

Comment: label value map be anything so shall use"{label.text+ slider.value*150}"